# VB.NET How to edit the HTML code of my active web page in my WebBrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, web

I made an application with a WebBrowser then I want to change the html code of the active page in the web browser. I don't want to got the html code, but edit it like in chrome or other browser, Right Click then Edit Element.

Thanks for helping and aswering ! :)

Comment: you can't do that. Use notepad and reload the page

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish by editing this code? This question is very vague. It would help if there were a specific problem presented, as well as how you have attempted to solve the problem thus far.

Comment: I can't use notepad to edit an online web page ! For exemple, I want the edit the html code of this web site: [link]www.zitrotechapps.esy.es/[/link]. On Google Chrome, I just need to do Right Click->Inspect the element. I want t know if its possible to 'Inspect the element' of a web page like on Chrome.